# Data passing by via @Input()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I have a question with data passing to component using `@Input()`. When i have a `list` component that contains some data. When i click `edit` an `view` button it loads some component. in my `detailComponent`:

```
@Input() serviceTimeGoal: IServiceTimeGoal;
```

And my update component same as detail. But detail component works fine. But update component receives no data. Here is i am opening modal:

```
 <table
        class="table table-striped table-bordered table=hover"
        aria-describedby="page-heading"
      >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col"><span>Үүсгэсэн огноо</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><span>Үүсгэсэн хэрэглэгч</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><span>Шинэчилсэн огноо</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><span>Шинэчилсэн хэрэглэгч</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><span>Идэвхитэй</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><span>Хугацаа</span></th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let serviceTimeGoal of serviceTimeGoals; let i = index">
            <td>{{ serviceTimeGoal.createdAt | dateFormatPipe }}</td>
            <td>{{ serviceTimeGoal.createdBy }}</td>
            <td>{{ serviceTimeGoal.updatedAt | dateFormatPipe }}</td>
            <td>{{ serviceTimeGoal.updatedBy }}</td>
            <td>{{ serviceTimeGoal.enabled }}</td>
            <td>{{ serviceTimeGoal.time }}</td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  (click)="
                    openModal(serviceTimeGoal, 'service-time-goal', $event)
                  "
                  class="btn btn-info btn-sm"
                >
                  <i class="icon-eye"></i>
                </button>
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                  (click)="
                    openModal(serviceTimeGoal, 'update-service-time', $event)
                  "
                >
                  <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
                </button>
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  [routerLink]="[
                    '/service-time-goal',
                    {
                      outlets: {
                        popup: serviceTimeGoal.id.branchId + '/delete'
                      }
                    }
                  ]"
                  replaceUrl="true"
                  queryParamsHandling="merge"
                  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                >
                  <i class="icon-bin"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
 </table>

<!-- Update component -->
<qms-modal id="update-service-time">
  <qms-service-time-goal-update
    [serviceTimeGoal]="serviceTimeGoal"
  ></qms-service-time-goal-update>
</qms-modal>

<!-- Detail component -->
<qms-modal id="service-time-goal">
  <qms-service-time-goal-detail
    [serviceTimeGoal]="serviceTimeGoal"
  ></qms-service-time-goal-detail>
</qms-modal>
```

And in my `ts` file:

```
openModal(serviceTimeGoal: IServiceTimeGoal, id: string, e: any) {
    this.singleData = serviceTimeGoal;
    this.modalService.open(id);
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

What am i doing wrong any advice ?

**EDIT:**

updateComponent:

```
@Input() serviceTimeGoal: IServiceTimeGoal;

ngOnInit() {
    this.isSaving = false;
    this.updateForm(this.serviceTimeGoal);
}

    updateForm(serviceTimeGoal: IServiceTimeGoal) {
    console.log(serviceTimeGoal);
    this.editForm.patchValue({
      cat: serviceTimeGoal.id.cat,
      reg: serviceTimeGoal.id.reg,
      loc: serviceTimeGoal.id.loc,
      name: serviceTimeGoal.id.name,
      tx1: serviceTimeGoal.id.tx1,
      tx2: serviceTimeGoal.id.tx2,
      tx3: serviceTimeGoal.id.tx3,
      tx4: serviceTimeGoal.id.tx4,
      createdBy: serviceTimeGoal.createdBy,
      updatedBy: serviceTimeGoal.updatedBy,
      enabled: serviceTimeGoal.enabled,
      time: serviceTimeGoal.time
    });
  }
```

detailComponent:

```
@Input() serviceTimeGoal: IServiceTimeGoal;
```

Update:

[image]
Detail:

[image]

Comment: Can you add code base for both Detail and Update component?

Comment: @JuChengJiang edited

Comment: @Poldo i already did.

Comment: @Poldo updated my question

Comment: ok. Have you imported both Update and Detail component as a child component in parent component?

Comment: @JuChengJiang no

Comment: @JuChengJiang my two components not related with list component.

Comment: Data should be pass to child elements So you will need to import both child components in the parent component.

Comment: Yes. but what I mean is that @input will work when you send data from Parent component to Child component. Otherwise, it can't be work.

Comment: @JuChengJiang then why first component works ?

Comment: because it was already defined as child component

Comment: then in list component i need to do `import { ServiceTimeGoalDetailComponent } from "./service-time-goal-detail.component";
import { ServiceTimeGoalUpdateComponent } from "./service-time-goal-update.component";` ?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/Input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to share same data between multiple components, I think using a shared service will be more efficient. You can find some sample code snippets [here](https://medium.com/@chameeradulanga87/sharing-data-between-angular-components-f76fa680bf76).

Comment: but the problem is two components already initialised in list component.

Comment: I fixed it. It's caused when the two components already in list component something happens.